# How can a Facebook page's post be shared from a share when no one has shared the said post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-insights

So I was checking one of my Facebook page's specific post insights. Although "*Likes/Comments on post*" and "*Likes/Comments on shares*" are pretty explicit, I'm wondering what exactly "**Shares on shares**" means when the post hasn't been shared yet ("*Shares on post*" is `0`)?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

And here's a screenshot of the whole post:

[image]

And the same happened with a post from 20 minutes ago:

[image]

How can a post be shared from a share when no one has shared the said post?

Comment: Is there a date range for these metrics? Is it possible the "share on share" happened during the time period but the "share on post" occurred outside the date range? Based on what I'm seeing in the Facebook help articles you can set a date range when viewing these type of metrics.

Comment: @Folk: I wasn't aware of that (setting a date range when viewing this type of metrics). AFAIK, no, there isn't any date restriction on the screenshot (I just clicked on the reach below the post).

Comment: Would it be possible to add a screenshot that shows this entire screen? This would add some context to what we already are able to see.

Comment: @Folk: Just did! (of course, some insights have raised since first screenshot - not shares *hopefully*).

Answer (score 2):

This boils down to the visibility of actions taken on Facebook.

- Likes and Comments on public posts are visible publicly. All of them will
  show up on your Page’s post.
- Shares have their own visibility setting, specified by the person who
  shared the post. If you are unable to view the shared post, then that
  action will not be visible to you on your own post.

You can verify this by having a friend Share your post with only themselves, on their own Timeline. If your friend then views your post, the number of Shares will be incremented by 1 to reflect their recent Share. If you view your own post, that Share will not show up.

Comment: AFAIK, even *private* shares are counted in these insights. You're just not able to see them when clicking on "XX shares" below the likes that lists every shares of the post.

Comment: My Insights do show some Likes and Reactions on Shares. However, my number of Shares under Insights has been stuck at 0, even after I performed the test above. So I would be inclined to say that private Shares do not show up under Insights. It could also be a bug. Hard to tell.

Comment: As far as I can remember, I've always seen the total number of shares of the post in those insights. Most of the time, this number is greated than the one listed below the likes on the post.

Comment: Well, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, try to see where the post originated and click that link. If you're successful in bringing up the original post, then you should be able to share that from it's origin.
Hope that helps.. Let us know.  Thanks.